# Convert int list to string with comma SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

How convert a list of int to string with comma with function in SQL Server?

[image]

Convert to : "68,74,58,64,67"

Comment: Google:  "sql server aggregate string concat"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
create table t (ProductId int);
insert into t values (68) ,(74) ,(58) ,(64) ,(67);

select 
    ProductIds = stuff((
        select ','+convert(varchar(10),ProductId)
        from t
        for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
      ,1,1,'')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RZQF31435

returns:

```
+----------------+
|   ProductIds   |
+----------------+
| 68,74,58,64,67 |
+----------------+
```

edit:  In SQL Server 2017+, you can use `string_agg()`, and the performance appears to be the same based on Jeffry Schwartz's article: [Should I Replace My FOR XML PATH String Merges with String_agg?](https://www.sqlrx.com/should-i-replace-my-for-xml-path-string-merges-with-string_agg/)

Comment: Watching Invader Zim on DVD...  Lots of yelling.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I balance it out by keeping my sql lower case ^.^

Comment: while i apply where clause query return null

Answer (score 1):

You can use stuff and xml path for concatenation and selection data from after first comma..

```
select distinct stuff((select ',' + convert(char(2), productid) from #yourproductid for xml path('')),1,1, '') 
    from #yourproductid
```

Your table :

```
create table #yourproductid(productid int) 

insert into #yourproductid (productid) values (68),(74),(58),(64),(67)
```